# how can i use Indian Rupee Sign in Javafx or Fxml

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml, javafx-8

how can i use Indian Rupee Sign in Javafx or Fxml ??

```
 Label l2 = new Label("Here I want to put Indian Rupee Sign ");
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
Label l2 = new Label("Rupee sign: \u20B9");
```

(According to Wikipedia this is the Rupee sign: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign encoded as Unicode)

Comment: Make sure the font you are using contains the symbol in question (it obviously doesn't).

Comment: please use for this `System.out.println("Rupee sign: \u20A8");`

Comment: Ref:http://defenceforumindia.com/forum/members-corner/33869-indian-rupee-symbol-unicode-font-working-you.html

Answer (score 0):

Unicode Character 'INDIAN RUPEE SIGN' (U+20B9).This unicode symbol show in Version of `6.0.0`

- Enter in your terminal in `echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"` output is `☠`
- In Indian Ruppes sign in `echo -e "\xE2\x82\xB9"`  output is `₹` means not support in Indian rupee,Ref [Unicode has become the dominant scheme for internal processing and storage of text. Although a great deal of text is still stored in legacy encodings, Unicode is used almost exclusively for building new information processing systems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

Other than use this unicode `System.out.println("Rupee sign: \u20A8");` this unicode ouput is `₨`

Ref [Unicode In INdian Rupee sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `(char)Integer.parseInt("20B9",16);`

[image: Currency symbols in ComboBox]

Comment: Already did. Assign the return value to whatever control you want.

`Label lb = new Label();`
`lb.setText(Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt("20B9",16)));`

Comment: Hey I am using Javafx2 and jdk7_u41 but this shows only Rectangle should i need to do any other configuration.

Comment: Works like charm for me. And i dont have any additional configuration other than the shared code. I am on JDK 7u45.

Comment: @javababa if you still havent figured this out, i observed this code doesnt work if you are using a different font. I changed the font to Arial and it was showing rectangular box to me.